# object list inside object list with backbone

Tags: templates, backbone.js

I have a structure to display in my App. Can anyone have an idea how to display following structure?I tried with handlebarJS inside backbone but it is not working for me..

```
 1) Json object has list of objects A 
 2) A has prop A and list of objects B
 3) B has list of objects B1,B2,B3
 4) each of B1,B2,B3 has 2 properties.
```

so legend label is prop A(name)

```
   inside B1.string1  B1.string2

   inside B2.string1  B2.string2         

   inside B2.string1  B2.string2
```

code:

```
PersonItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.template2 = _.template($('#temp').html());
    },
    render: function () {
        $(this.el).html( this.template2( this.model.toJSON()));

        return this;
    }
});

PeopleListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function () {
        var people = [];

        this.collection.each(function (model) {

            var view = new PersonItemView({ model : model });

            people.push( view.render().el); 
        });

        this.$el.append(people);

        return this;
    }
});
```

In my template I am able to print people.name as filed set legend but inside of that fieldsett I am looping people.objects like below

```
<fieldset> 
    <legend>{{name}}</legend>

    {{#each people.objectList}}

    <label>{{string1}}</label>

    <label>{{string2}}</label>

    {{/each}}

</fieldset>
```

In firebug I am seeing below error and pointing to # character:

```
SyntaxError: illegal character ((__t=(#each Obj))==null?'':__t)+
```

Is there any other way to do it in collections?

Comment: what isn't working and what have you tried?

Comment: Do you have a template you're using with this data? If so, which templating engine do you want to use?

Comment: yes I am using template..I just edited my main post...u can see the code now...

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see is in the render call for your PeopleListView when you try to append an array into your view's el:

```
this.collection.each(function (model) {

    var view = new PersonItemView({ model : model });

    people.push( view.render().el); 
});

this.$el.append(people);
```

Either you need to append the el from the view.render call in the loop:

```
this.collection.each(function (model) {

    var view = new PersonItemView({ model: model });

    this.$el.append(view.render().el);
});
```

or you need to convert that array to straight markup before you append it:

```
this.collection.each(function (model) {

    var view = new PersonItemView({ model: model });

    people.push(view.render().el);
});

this.$el.append(people.join(''));
```